# AVERAGEIF() - excluding dates that are equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Sheet that has readings from various dates. Sometimes there are more than one reading on a given day. I want to get the mean from only the first readings each day. So, I need an `AVERAGEIF()` that excludes an observation if the previous date was the same.
      `=AVERAGEIF(R3C2:R24C2, "<>"&R[-1]C2, R3C4:R24C4)`

Doesn't seem to work.

[image: sample spreadsheet image]

Comment: You can't use `AVERAGEIF` for this but you can use this array formula: `=AVERAGE(IF(R3C2:R24C2<>R2C2:R23C2,R3C4:R24C4))`...comparing your range against the same size range starting a row higher

Comment: Thanks! This worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MATCH(R3C2:R24C2,R3C2:R24C2,0)=ROW(R3C2:R24C2)-MIN(ROW(R3C2:R24C2))+1,R3C4:R24C4))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

For those not using R1C1 notation:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MATCH($B$3:$B$24,$B$3:$B$24,0)=ROW($B$3:$B$24)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$24))+1,$D$3:$D$24))
```

Comment: Barry Houdini's formula was simpler and seemed to work, but you get +1 for telling me I needed to use ctl-shift-enter to use an array formula.

Comment: @SteveScher the difference between mine and his is how the data is sorted.  If the data is always sorted on the Date/Time then yes use his.  If your data is not sorted then use mine.